# Weird Entity Framework error: login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have an application with multiple `DbContext` subclasses that share a connection string (this is to avoid EF's horrible startup time with a single large `DbContext` type). At certain points (repeatable for me and somewhat for others), I get the following error when trying to make a database query:

> *System.Data.EntityException: "The underlying provider failed on Open."
>
>   with inner exception:
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException "Login failed
>   for user 'username'"*

The problem appears to go away if I switch back to using a single giant `DbContext`.

Does anyone know what this means/how to fix it? Would it help if I reused the same `DbConnection` object across `DbContexts` (as opposed to just using the same connection string)? This connection string has already succeeded in making several queries in the same request, so it can't be that the credentials are bad.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, EF 4.3.1, .NET 4.0, VS 2010.

The relevant stack trace is below:

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'testing_net'.]
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6351920
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1363
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +53
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6366878
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6366793
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean  redirectedUserInstance) +352
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +831
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +49
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +6368598
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +78
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +2194
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +89
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6372110
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection  storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +67

 [EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +11108990
    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +142
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +97
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +57
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +47
    System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +156
```

A rough outline of the code is as follows:

```
// db context:
public class MyDbContext<T> : DbContext {
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // constructs the model base on the type of T
        // code first POCO entities are annotated with an attribute that links
        // them to one or more types T
    }
}
```

I use AutoFac's DI to inject my DbContext's into the services my data access layer. The lifespan of the context is length of the HttpRequest.

The actual exception occurs on a call to Queryable.Single().

EDIT: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987787/entity-framework-giving-exception-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open) question might be relevant, but I'm not sure what to make of the race condition described.

EDIT: Now that I understand the issue, I can post the offending piece of code:

```
MyDbContext<T1> db1 = ...
var connectionString = db1.Database.Connection.ConnectionString; 
var dbContext2 = new MyDbContext<T2>(connectionString);
```

Comment: also can you show the code where you are defining the DbContext as well as how you are passing username and pw to the connection if necessary..?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: yes. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: Does your connection string contain `AttachDBFilename` or `User Instance`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: it doesn't contain either of those fields

Comment: Definitely sounds like we need to see the code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I've posted a basic outline of what my code is doing. Unfortunately, I've been unable to construct a standalone example that runs in isolation. Please let me know what else specifically might be helpful!

Comment: @Chasemedallion - Your co-worker Sidaway, said that his testing showed that the size of the context was irrelevant to the startup time, and that the only thing that affected it was x86 or x64.  Further, the problem was related to nUnit according to his post.  So if that's the case, then why are you still breaking up your contexts?

Comment: @MystereMan: since you're curious, the 7-second global EF startup time mentioned in the other question was indeed determined by platform/nUnit vs. running via the console and appeared to be independent of model size. However, we are in the process of breaking up our datacontexts because for very large models we have found that the model-creation time explodes non-linearly (a model with 800+ entities takes > 1 minute!). There are several other references to this problem on SO, but the only current fix (pre-compiled views) provides only a partial solution. Thus, the two are separate issues.

Comment: What happens if you place the contexts in different assemblies?

Comment: @MystereMan: given that I have a single generic context, how can I place it in different assemblies? Even if I go and create lots of concrete DbContext types, why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Chasemedallion - because it doesn't matter if your base class is in the same assembly, it could matter if the final instances are in different assemblies.  I've seen in EF where two contexts in the same assembly cause weird problems (although that was when using a .edmx file, so it may not apply to code first, but it couldn't hurt to test and find out).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was related to the PersistSecurityInfo connection string property. From MSDN:

> PersistSecurityInfo: Gets or sets a Boolean value that indicates if
>   security-sensitive information, such as the password, is not returned
>   as part of the connection if the connection is open or has ever been
>   in an open state.

My connection string originally had a username and password in it. I would initialize a DbContext with this string, then later initialize a different context using the same string in the initial context's Database.Connection property. However, because PersistSecurityInfo was set to false, in some scenarios the password silently vanished from the connection's reference to the connection string, leading to login failure on the new DbContext instance.

The possible solutions I've thought of are to:
1. Set PersistSecurityInfo to true
2. Keep a separate reference to the connection string and use that
3. Use a different form of authentication that doesn't put the username and password in the connection string

Comment: I had the same situation as you have described. Thank you for this. How this is even a thing after 8 years, in EF 6.4 version!? This is unbelievable...

Comment: @MateuszMyślak I agree it is frustrating, but the behavior isn't EF-specific; it is part of ADO.NET and considered a security feature to make it harder for credentials to leak unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the user should have some roles that are db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, db_owner or db_securityadmin. About more roles information, please refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I had forgotten to change the integrated security to false and add the local user id and password to the connection string in the web config file.